# How to solve this integral: $ \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{x^4}{a^x+1}dx $?

Tags: calculus

I got this at my final calculus 1 exam. Any help with the solution?

$$ \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{x^4}{a^x+1}dx $$

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT:

Use $$I=\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx$$

and $$I+I=\int_a^bf(x)dx+\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx=\int_a^b[f(x)+f(a+b-x)]dx$$

Comment: nice trick, (+1)

Comment: +1. An old trick that leads to$$I=\frac12\int_{-1}^1x^4\ dx.$$

Comment: Thank you all for your answers!

Answer (score 6):

Computing the even part of the integrand, one obtains
$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{x^4dx}{a^x+1}=\frac12\int_{-1}^1 \underbrace{\left[\frac{1}{a^x+1}+\frac{1}{a^{-x}+1}\right]}_{=1}x^4dx=\frac{x^5}{10}\biggl|_{-1}^1=\frac15.$$